# How to display count of a column based on other column value conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table data in my table

```
SQL> select * from mate2;  

     A_CD       S_ID       E_CD S_E   S_NE  E_IND  
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----- -  
       200          1          2 A     J     Y  
       200          2          3 B     A     N  
       200          3          1 C     D  
       200          4          2 A     C     Y  
       200          5          1 D     C  
       200          6          3 B     N     Y  
       200          7          3 N     K
```

I need to get count of distinct s_id group by a_cd and (S_E, S_NE) as letter codes with below conditions

1) take the S_NE when E_CD = 2 or (E_CD = 3 AND E_IND = N)

2) take the S_E when E_CD = 1 or (E_CD = 3 AND E_IND = Y)

3) take BOTH the S_E and S_NE when E_CD = 3 and E_IND is null

The output should be like

200 A 3
200 B 2
200 c 2
..
...
I have written something like this but its not working

```
select a.a_cd, a.letter_code, COUNT (DISTINCT a.s_id) AS cnt  
           FROM (SELECT m.a_cd,  
                        m.s_id,  
                        CASE  
                           WHEN    (m.e_cd = 1)  
                                OR (m.e_cd = 3 AND m.e_ind = 'Y')  
                           THEN  
                              m.S_E  
                           WHEN (m.e_cd = 2) OR (m.e_cd = 3 AND m.e_ind = 'N') then  m.S_NE  
                           WHEN m.e_ind is null then m.S_NE                      
                        END  
                           AS letter_code from mate2 m  
                   union  
                   SELECT m.a_cd,  
                        m.s_id,  
                        CASE  
                           WHEN    (m.e_cd = 1)  
                                OR (m.e_cd = 3 AND m.e_ind = 'Y')  
                           THEN  
                              m.S_E  
                           WHEN (m.e_cd = 2) OR (m.e_cd = 3 AND m.e_ind = 'N') then  m.S_NE  
                           WHEN m.e_ind is null then m.S_NE                      
                        END  
                           AS letter_code from mate2 m) a group by a.ai_cd,a.letter_code
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about your groupping criterias. Also your example output doesn't match your selection criteria.

However below you'll find a query that should pick the correct intermediate result set based on your rules. Just make the correct groupping based on that.

```
with
mate2(  a_cd, s_id, e_cd, s_e, s_ne, e_ind) as (  
  select 200,    1,    2, 'A',  'J', 'Y'  from dual union all
  select 200,    2,    3, 'B',  'A', 'N'  from dual union all
  select 200,    3,    1, 'C',  'D', null from dual union all
  select 200,    4,    2, 'A',  'C', 'Y'  from dual union all
  select 200,    5,    1, 'D',  'C', null from dual union all
  select 200,    6,    3, 'B',  'N', 'Y'  from dual union all
  select 200,    7,    3, 'N',  'K', null from dual
),
rule_1(rule, a_cd, s_id, letter_code) as (
  -- take the S_NE when E_CD = 2 or (E_CD = 3 AND E_IND = N)
  select 1, a_cd, s_id, s_ne from mate2 where e_cd = 2 or (e_cd = 3 and e_ind = 'N')
),
rule_2(rule, a_cd, s_id, letter_code) as (
  -- take the S_E when E_CD = 1 or (E_CD = 3 AND E_IND = Y)
  select 2, a_cd, s_id, s_e from mate2 where e_cd = 1 or (e_cd = 3 and e_ind = 'Y')
),
rule_3(rule, a_cd, s_id, letter_code) as (
  -- take BOTH the S_E and S_NE when E_CD = 3 and E_IND is null
  select 3, a_cd, s_id, letter_code from mate2 
  unpivot (letter_code for x in (s_ne as '1', s_e as '2'))
  where e_cd = 3 and e_ind is null 
)
-- group the way you like
--select letter_code, count(*) from (
  select * from rule_1
  union all
  select * from rule_2
  union all
  select * from rule_3
--) group by letter_code
--order by 1
;
```